# connecting to cassandra using datastax' connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra-2.0, datastax

When I'm trying to connect to the cassandra seed node using the datastax connector, I can't.

I have four spark nodes: one master and three workers. This works well on its own. The same machines have cassandra installed on them with the one being the spark master as a seed node. This works on its own as well (I successfully wrote and read from it).

Now, I'm trying to do

```
val info = spark_context.cassandraTable("files", "metainfo")
println( info.count )
```

Before, I specify the spark context as follows:

```
     val confStandalone = new SparkConf()
       .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "10.14.56.156")
       .setMaster("spark://10.14.56.156:7077")
       .setAppName("Test")
       .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
       .set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
       .set("spark.driver.host", "10.14.56.156")
       .set("spark.broadcast.factory", "org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory")

     val spark_context = new SparkContext( confStandalone )
     spark_context.addJar("SOME_PATH/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.2.0-alpha1.jar")
```

In the cassandra.yaml file I set the rpc_address to 10.14.56.156 and used the standard ports (9160, 9042). Now when I do

```
sbt run
```

I get the following error:

```
15/03/18 16:38:43 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Adding host 127.0.0.1 (datacenter1)
15/03/18 16:38:43 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Adding host 10.14.56.156 (datacenter1)
15/03/18 16:38:43 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Adding host 127.0.0.1 (datacenter1)
15/03/18 16:38:43 ERROR Session: Error creating pool to /127.0.0.1:9042 com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:106)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.PooledConnection.<init>(PooledConnection.java:35)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:528)
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9042 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
...
```

Now, when I change the rpc_address to 0.0.0.0 as id sometimes advised, I get the same error but with 10.14.56.156 instead of 127.0.0.1 and only the line:

```
15/03/18 16:38:43 INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Adding host 10.14.56.156 (datacenter1)
```

with the one above and the one below (referring to 127.0.0.1) removed.

I didn't set any firewall rules in the iptables, so I don't think that would be an issue. Help appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify, by changing the rpc_address to 0.0.0.0 you are now getting the '[/X.X.X.X:9042] Cannot connect' error but with '10.14.56.156' instead?

Comment: yes, that's what's happening

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at what broadcast_rpc_address is set to?   The java-driver will derive the ip to connect to from the 'peer' column of system.peers.  If rpc_address is set to 0.0.0.0, broadcast_rpc_address must be set.

My guess is that with your rpc_address set to 0.0.0.0, the driver is connecting from the broadcast_rpc_address even though it says `[/10.14.56.156:9042] Cannot connect` (you may see `Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9042 further in the stack trace`).

Comment: Hey Andy, thanks for your response. So I set the rpc_address to 0.0.0.0 and broadcast address to 10.14.56.156 and that error went away, but now its losing tasks with the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/driver/core/Statement`. I'm searching how to fix that and why it started coming up. So thanks for helping me solve the previous issue but maybe this one is related... So if you had some suggestions it would be great:)

Comment: That's interesting, statement is a core piece of the driver so I'm surprised to see you can connect with the driver (which uses statements as part of initialization) but get a NCDFError.  I'm not very versed in the spark component, but is that failure happening on your spark workers?  Do you need to add the driver & spark connector to your classpath?

Comment: I did add the jar to the spark context, which as far as I understand, should ship it to the workers. In case that wasn't right I've just tried adding `spark.executor.extraClassPath` to the sparkConf and placing the jar in that location on each of the workers as well as the master. But the same thing keeps happening

Comment: Are you able to determine if the error is happening on the worker or on the client application running the datastax spark connector?  Unfortunately this is getting out of my realm expertise, now I'm curious as to what the solution is! :)